# Getting phantomjs/spiderable to work behind nginx on ec2

Tags: meteor, nginx, amazon-ec2, phantomjs

We're having real problems trying to get spiderable to return body content from a meteor app deployed behind nginx on ec2. When we do:

```
$ curl https://host/?_escaped_fragment_=
```

(Note the SSL)

We always get an `internal server error`. Getting a page without the `?_escaped_frament` returns a page with full headers but an empty body. (Reminds me of *Big Head* on HBO's Silicon Valley)

Subscriptions are properly handled with `this.ready()` in `iron-router` as many have recommended. That's not the problem. Relevant packages include:

- `jazeee:spiderable-longer-timeout`
- `spiderable`
- `gadicohen:phantomjs`

A gaggle of googling has yielded suggestions to use various forks of spiderable along with some opaque suggestions on configuring nginx. Can you recommend a *working* configuration of packages and nginx configuration? Bonus points for explaining *why* it works.

Comment: This is killing me.  I've tried a number of these suggestions as well with little to no luck.